# vb.net string contains only 4 digit numbers(or a year)

Tags: vb.net, string, digits

how can i check if a string only contains 4 digit numbers ( or a year )
i tried this

```
 Dim rgx As New Regex("^/d{4}")      
    Dim number As String = "0000"
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(number)) // true
    number = "000a"
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(number)) // false
    number = "000"
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(number)) //false
    number = "00000"
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(number))  // true <<< :(
```

this returns false when its less than 4 or at characters but not at more than 4

thanks!

Comment: what should i use then?

Comment: Writing up an answer now.

Comment: `Dim rgx As New Regex("^\d{4}$") `

Comment: Avinash Raj, that works :) but waiting on ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ for why i shoudnt use Regex

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ, `Try not to use Regex, it's not designed for this sort of thing` - that comment is a bit surprising.

Comment: @cel Regular expression is meant for string matching, although it *can* be used for this I'm a little surprised that the OP has gone down the path of using it.

Comment: Is 0123 a valid year? What about 9015?

Comment: @user2653652 I updated my answer to provide code that's better suited to what you're trying to do, please review it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually wouldn't use a regex for this. The expression is deceptively simple (`^\d{4}$`), until you realize that you also need to evaluate that numeric value to determine a valid year range... unless you want years like `0013` or `9015`. You're most likely going to want the value as an integer in the end, anyway. Given that, the best validation is probably just to actually try to convert it to an integer right off the bat:

```
Dim numbers() As String = {"0000", "000a", "000", "00000"}
For Each number As String In numbers
    Dim n As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(number, n) AndAlso number.Length = 4 Then
        'It's a number. Now look at other criteria

    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Ironic, `Integer.TryParse` is exactly the same as `IsNumeric`, just with additional verification.

Comment: the difference is i think that it parses it to a integer that cant have decimal numbers. and thats why it works for me i think

Comment: TryParse() is **NOT** the same as IsNumeric(). It actually produces an integer variable in the result. IsNumeric() uses a different implementation for compatibility with old code, and it's a naive and stupid function.

Comment: @user2653652 It's not just that it allows decimals. it's also that it deliberately preserves some ... odd behaviors for backwards compatibility purposes with code migrated from the vb6 era.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) characters [IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim result As Boolean = ((Not number Is Nothing) AndAlso ((number.Length = 4) AndAlso number.All(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))))
```

Comment: There's no error handling here, there are *hundreds* of situations where it could cause problems.

Comment: Error handling?? The number variable is defined and initialized as `Dim number As String = "0000"`. How can there be *"hundreds of situations where it could cause problems"*?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the .NET string manipulation functions.

Firstly the requirements, the string must:

- Contain *exactly* four characters, no more, no less;
- Must consist of a numeric value

However your aim is to validate a `Date`:

```
Function isKnownGoodDate(ByVal input As String) As Boolean 'Define the function and its return value.
    Try 'Try..Catch statement (error handling). Means an input with a space (for example ` ` won't cause a crash)
        If (IsNumeric(input)) Then 'Checks if the input is a number
            If (input.Length = 4) Then
                Dim MyDate As String = "#01/01/" + input + "#"
                If (IsDate(MyDate)) Then
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

You may experience a warning:

> Function `isKnownGoodDate` does not return a value on all code
>   paths. Are you missing a `Return` statement?

this can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks, just to be curious, why shoudnt i use Regex, something about performance?

Comment: and doesnt IsNumeric also return true on double?

Comment: IsNumeric() is a very naive evaluation. Not everything that evaluates as numeric can be converted to a number, and not everything that's a number evaluates as numeric.

Comment: i tested the code input = "00.1" also returns as true, and return false doesnt happen

Comment: @user2653652 Check the code I added, that should do the job for you (as I tested it myself), it's more likely to work for you since `Date` types cannot be `01/01/19.04`.

Comment: @user2653652 Just curious, are you attempting to validate dates with certain properties (e.g, dates which are in the future, in the past 100 years, etc)?